# Can you leverage OS specific desktop browser gestures?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, safari, gesture, safari-extension

No, it would not be a good idea to do so, but still a real question.

Example, Google Chrome allows OSX users to swipe back and forth to move back and forth between pages. Things like that. On mobile devices, you can leverage these gestures for your apps so I was wondering if there is a way to do the same for desktop browsers as well.

Maybe even a way to write an addon that will then be able to leverage these controls?

Comment: Safari, at least, has no documented API for accessing the browser's or OS X's gesture recognitions. That I'm aware of.

Comment: I figured as much. I couldn't find anything on Google and I tried scouring their Chrome docs as well and nothing there either.

Comment: I'm sure they don't allow it because some people would use them for no good. It would be VERY annoying if you were trying to use a feature specific to OSX that some web app or site was stealing from you.